# Connectedness of subspace of $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the space
$X=\{(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{C}):|x_k|=1\text{ for all }k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Is $X$ connected?

My first guess would be to say yes, given that it's just $(S^1)^\mathbb{N}$ (although with a different topology). Can anyone lead me in the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know how to show $S^1$ is connected?

Comment: Yes. The problem for me is relating the two topologies: the natural product topology on the product of circles and the subspace topology of $\ell_2$

Comment: Have you tried showing that it's path connected?

Comment: That's the strategy I would like to use. For example, if $(x_k)\in X$, then I could define $f:[0,1]\to X$ where $f(t)=((x_k)^t)$. At 0 it is $(1)\in X$, and at 1 it is the original element. But is f continuous?

Comment: it seems like the important thing is that all the paths in each of the components have bounded speed, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Show that $(x_k) \to (\frac {e^{x_k}} {|e^{x_k}|})$ is a continuous map from $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb C)$ onto the given set.

Comment: Ahhh very nice answer!